# How to make a comparator function inside any class just like we make in a priority_queue in c++ STL

Tags: c++, c++14

Just like in a priority_queue in STL we can give our custom compare function like this:

```
class comp
{
    bool operator()(int a, int b)
    {
        return a>b? 1:0;
    }
};
priority_queue<int, vector<int>, comp> pq;
```

How can I do this for any class? I tried doing this to compare my person class object using `class c`:

```
class person
{
  public:
  int height;
  int age;
  person(int a, int h)
  { 
     age = a;
     height = h;
  }
};

template<class comparator>
class c
{
   public:
   vector<person>p;
   void compare(person p1, person p2)
   {
     if(comparator comp( p1,  p2))
     {
      p.push_back(p1);
     }
   }
};

class compare
{
    bool operator()(person p1, person p2)
    {
        return p1.height> p2.height ? 1:0;
    }
};
```

and then I created 2 `person` objects and a `class c` object "pq", then called the `compare` function like we do in `priority_queue`:

```
person p1(23, 85);
person p2(11, 55);
c <compare> pq;
pq.compare(p1, p2);
```

but it is giving this error.

```
    error: expected primary-expression before 'comp'
             if(comparator comp(p1, p2))
                           ^~~~
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to create an instance of the functor you want to compare with, and then call that instance's `operator()`.

This:

```cpp
if(comparator comp( p1,  p2))
```

does not do that. You seem to be trying to just construct a `comparator` called `comp` in the `if` condition - which can't be done - and then made no effort actually to call said `comparator` anyway. Change that to this:

```cpp
   void compare(person p1, person p2)
   {
     if (comparator{}(p1, p2)) // fixed
     {
       p.push_back(p1);
     }
   }
```

That is: first construct a `comparator` with `{}`, and then call its `operator()` with `()`.

That, in turn, means you need its `operator()` to be accessible outwith itself:

```cpp
class compare
{
public: // added (or omit this and change class to struct)
    bool operator()(person p1, person p2)
    {
        return p1.height> p2.height ? 1:0;
    }
};
```

With these changes, it compiles fine. I didn't check whether it does what you want, but you obviously need to fix these syntax errors first.